# How can a command take #1 as an argument?

Tags: macros

I was wondering how some commands manage to take `#1` as an argument when **used**, not when declared.

For instance, biblatex's `\DeclareFieldFormat` can be **used** like this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat {postnote} {#1}
```

I have taken a look at `biblatex1.sty` (lines 3480--3506, v2.3, revison 28161) but couldn't figure out how it can do that. Where is the trick?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
\foo {bar} {\textbf{#1}}
```

I want it to typeset **bar** in bold face; that is, to typeset whatever is given in the first argument in whatever format is given in the second one.

#### From `biblatex1.sty`:

```
%---CUT---
\newrobustcmd*{\DeclareFieldFormat}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\blx@defformat\blx@defplainformat{ffd}*}
    {\blx@defformat\blx@defplainformat{ffd}{}}}
%---CUT---

% {<macro>}{<class>}{<*>}

\def\blx@defformat#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@defformat@i{#1}{#2}{#3}}
    {\blx@defformat@i{#1}{#2}{#3}[*]}}

% {<macro>}{<class>}{<*>}[<entrytype>]{<name>}

\def\blx@defformat@i#1#2#3[#4]#5{%
  \notblank{#3}
    {\blx@resetformat{#2}{#5}}
    {}%
  \def\blx@defformat@a{#2}%
  \def\blx@defformat@b{#4}%
  \blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\blx@defformat@c}{#5}%
  \afterassignment\blx@defformat@ii
  #1}
%---CUT---
```

Comment: I've removed the `biblatex` tag: the issue is noting to do with `biblatex`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need an auxiliary function, which is defined with one argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \def\fooaux##1{#2}%
  \fooaux{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\fooaux}[1]{}
\begin{document}
\foo{bar}{\textbf{#1,}} hhhh
\end{document}
```

The idea here is that `\fooaux` will end up defined as equivalent to

```
\renewcommand{\fooaux}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1,}%
}
```

in the code above.